# Django forms : 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'is_valid'

Tags: python, django

Like a lot of people here, i have to deal with a form problem, but even with other posts I can't see the solution, here are my files : **testeuh/models.py** :

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib import admin

# Create your models here.
class diapo(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    corpus = models.TextField(max_length=300)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="DossierImages")

class diapoAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    search_fields = ['title']
    list_display = ['title']
```

**testeuh/forms.py :**

```
from django.forms import ModelForm

from .models import diapo

def DiapoForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = diapo
        fields = [
            'title',
            'corpus',
            'image',
        ]
```

**testeuh/views.py :**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .forms import DiapoForm
from .models import diapo
# Create your views here.

def diapo_create_view(request):
    form = DiapoForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
    context = {
        'form': form
    }
    return render(request, "diapo/create.html", context)

def diapo_detail_view(request):
    obj = diapo.objects.get(id=1)
    context = {
        "object" : obj
    }
    return render(request, "diapo/detail.html", context)
```

**urls.py :**

```
"""SiteEcran URL Configuration

The `urlpatterns` list routes URLs to views. For more information please see:
    https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/http/urls/
Examples:
Function views
    1. Add an import:  from my_app import views
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('', views.home, name='home')
Class-based views
    1. Add an import:  from other_app.views import Home
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('', Home.as_view(), name='home')
Including another URLconf
    1. Import the include() function: from django.urls import include, path
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('blog/', include('blog.urls'))
"""
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from pages.views import home_view
from testeuh.views import diapo_detail_view
from testeuh.views import diapo_create_view

urlpatterns = [
    path('create/', diapo_create_view),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', home_view, name='home'),
    path('diapo/', diapo_detail_view, name='diapo'),
]
```

and **testeuh/templates/diapo/create.html :**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}

<form>
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type='submit' value='Save' />
</form>

{% endblock %}
```

Doing that (copying this tutorial at ~2h08 : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F5mRW0jo-U4) I get the following error : AttributeError at /create/
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'is_valid'
at  /home/raptorjesus/Desktop/SiteEcran/testeuh/views.py, line 8, in diapo_create_view
I don't understand why is DiapoForm(request.POST or None) returns a None object. If I had more "security", by introcucing code like that

```
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.is_valid():
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/thanks/')
    return render(request, 'my_template.html', {'form': form})
```

I do not crash anymore but the webpage is rendered without any entry zones, only the "save" button. Anyone to save me pls ?

Comment: Have you checked if you are actually receiving a POST request or not.

Comment: @sumitsubedi but I can't receive anything since the page with the form crash when I open it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm just so much stupid. It is the solution :

```
from django.forms import ModelForm

from .models import diapo

class DiapoForm(ModelForm): #put class instead of def...
    class Meta:
        model = diapo
        fields = [
            'title',
            'corpus',
            'image',
        ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your error is for GET request also your code is looking for posted form. Seperate your POST request from GET request doing this:

```
def diapo_create_view(request):
    
    if request.method=='POST':
        form = DiapoForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
    form = DiapoForm()
    context = {
        'form': form
    }
    return render(request, "diapo/create.html", context)
```

Comment: It's doing the same as the last block of code I mentionned : I only see a "save" button, which make the website to crash when I click on it.

Comment: I have edited the original answer can you check it once.

Comment: I get
```TypeError at /create/
DiapoForm() missing 1 required positional argument: 'ModelForm'
```
from you seventh line

Comment: Give None as instance like DiapoForm(None) in that form.

Comment: I get the exact same error, I just have a "save" button which makes the site to crash. If it can help, in the server terminal I have : 
`[25/May/2021 17:49:52] "GET /create/ HTTP/1.1" 200 335` then  
the error due to 'is_valid' and then
`[25/May/2021 17:50:11] "POST /create/ HTTP/1.1" 500 65882`